# Crear, modificar y eliminar columnas

Tags: python

- El DataFrame de entrada contiene una columna llamada 'Debut' y una columna llamada 'Debut deportivo' que son de tipo object
- El DataFrame de salida contiene el mismo número de columnas que el DataFrame de entrada porque añade dos columnas nuevas: `fecha_debut` de tipo int32 y `club_debut` de tipo object (que equivale a str) y elimina dos columnas: `Debut` y `Debut deportivo`
- La columna 'fecha_debut' solo tendrá valores nulos cuando las columnas 'Debut' y 'Debut deportivo' tengan valores nulos
- La columna 'club_debut' tendrá valores nulos cuando 'Debut deportivo' tenga valores nulos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo hago esto, pero no me efectúa lo que quiero. Llevo una semana y no me es suficiente para saber todavía como hacer estas cosas.

```
``def extraer_datos_debut(df):
 df = pd.DataFrame({"Debut": [np.NaN],  "Debut deportivo": [np.NaN]})
 df['fecha_debut'] = df['Debut'].str.extract('([0-9]{4})')
 df['club_debut'] = df['Debut deportivo'].str.extract('((?<=\()(.+)(?=\)))')[0]
 df.drop(columns= ['Debut deportivo'], inplace = True) 
 df.drop(columns= ['Debut'], inplace = True) 
 assert(isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame))
 return df   
 extraer_datos_debut(df)``
```

Me da IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.

Answer (score 1):

Los principales problemas que tienes en tu código son que:

- Eliminas las columnas "Debut" y "Debut deportivo" antes de usarlas, por lo que luego no se encuentran.
- Al hacer las extracciones no las estás asignando a ningún sitio.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Debut": ["27 de mayo de 2006", "21 de agosto de 2010", "21 de agosto de 2010", np.NaN], 
    "Debut deportivo": ["2006(UD Vecindario)", "11 de agosto de 2010(Portuguesa)", np.NaN, np.NaN]})


def extraer_datos_debut(df):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    new_df['fecha_debut'] = df['Debut'].str.extract('([0-9]{4})')
    new_df['club_debut'] = df['Debut deportivo'].str.extract('((?<=\()(.+)(?=\)))')[0]
    assert(isinstance(new_df, pd.DataFrame))
    return new_df


extraer_datos_debut(df)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. He actualizado mi código y me sigue dando error, pero hay que decir que cuando creo el df=pd.dataframe, en "Debut" y "Debut deportivo" los ejemplos son esos pero tengo que hacerlo para todas las columnas, no solo para las que puse de ejemplo. No sé si me he explicado. Es decir, tengo que restar las fechas en Debut Deportivo y quedarme solo con el año en Debut, pero para todas. Esa captura que puse es el ejemplo de lo que hay que lograr.

Comment: Si ejecutas el código que te he pasado no me da error y la salida es la que tú pones. Si te da error `IndentationError` es que tienes puestos mal los espacios/tabs. Indenta siempre con cuatro espacios y fíjate en la línea donde dice que está el error.

Comment: El código que me pasaste no da error, pero no necesito crear un nuevo df, sino que transformar el mismo. Respecto a la parte en la que haces el df = pd.DataFrame({]} es para todas las columnas. El ejemplo muestra como tienen que quedar, pero se debe aplicar a todas, no solo al Vecindario. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Reasigna con `df = extraer_datos_debut(df)` y haz drop de las columnas que no quieras como en tu ejemplo.

Comment: Lo siento, pero no entiendo lo que quieres decir. El drop ya está hecho, pero reasignar no sé donde ni por el por qué.